# PyCharm not detecting environment variables defined pre-launch

Tags: pycharm, environment-variables

To reproduce:

1. Shut down PyCharm.
2. Go to the terminal, run `export MYVAR="123"`
3. Open PyCharm
4. Open its Python console
5. Type `import os; os.environ['MYVAR']`
6. Output is: KeyError: 'MYVAR'

It was my understanding that PyCharm should take over any env vars that were defined at the moment of you starting the PyCharm application, but it is not the case here.

PyCharm 2022.2.2 (Edu)

Comment: How do you open PyCharm? If you do not open from the terminal, the variable should not be defined. It is not a problem of PyCharm, but how environmental variable works: parent send environmental variables to children. There is no global environmental variable (for very good reasons: we do not want that a program X change unrelated programs)